# How can I equalize the width columns 2-8?

Tags: tables, column-width

So now this table has been an uphill battle, but I'm not progressing anymore. When you see the image you know where I want to go =) I want the columuns 2-9 to assume the same width.

So this is what I have so far: 
[image: So this is what I have so far:]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Gas             & \multicolumn{ 7}{p{\linewidth}|}{Technischer Löslichkeitskoeffizient \lambda~in mL Gas/(1000~g Wasser $\cdot$ 1~bar) bei einer Temperatur in $\degree$C }   \\ \cline{2-8}
                & 0     & 5     & 10    & 15    & 20    & 25    & 30    \\     \hline
Sauerstoff      & 48,4  & 42,3  & 37,5  & 33,6  & 30,6  & 28,0  & 26,0  \\
Luft            & 28,6  & 25,5  & 22,4  & 20,4  & 18,3  & 16,3  & 15,3  \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (MWE). Btw: You seem to miss some math-mode around cdot.

Comment: done. ahh, so this is what the dollar signs do... already learned something =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can measure the width of the widest element in the first column, and then use that to calculate how wide the span from columns 2-8 should be:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} X }
\newlength{\tmplen}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\tmplen}{Sauerstoff}%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c *{7}{| C} |}
  \hline
  Gas             & \multicolumn{7}{ p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\tmplen-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth} | }{%
    Technischer Löslichkeitskoeffizient $\lambda$ in mL Gas/(1000~g Wasser $\cdot$ 1~bar) bei einer Temperatur in $^\circ$C } \\
  \cline{2-8}
                  & 0     & 5     & 10    & 15    & 20    & 25    & 30    \\
  \hline
  Sauerstoff      & 48,4  & 42,3  & 37,5  & 33,6  & 30,6  & 28,0  & 26,0  \\
  Luft            & 28,6  & 25,5  & 22,4  & 20,4  & 18,3  & 16,3  & 15,3  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} X }
\newlength{\tmplen}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\tmplen}{Sauerstoff}%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c *{7}{C} }
  \toprule
  Gas             & \multicolumn{7}{ p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\tmplen-4\tabcolsep} }{%
    \makecell[t]{Technischer Löslichkeitskoeffizient $\lambda$ \\
      in mL Gas/(1000~g Wasser $\cdot$ 1~bar) bei einer Temperatur in $^\circ$C }} \\
  \cmidrule{2-8}
                  & 0     & 5     & 10    & 15    & 20    & 25    & 30    \\
  \midrule
  Sauerstoff      & 48,4  & 42,3  & 37,5  & 33,6  & 30,6  & 28,0  & 26,0  \\
  Luft            & 28,6  & 25,5  & 22,4  & 20,4  & 18,3  & 16,3  & 15,3  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Upvote for `booktabs`! I'd like to mention `siunitx` to the OP in the context values with decimal dot or comma. It might be useful in further tables.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the long text should be an explanatory caption to the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\sisetup{locale=DE}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Technischer Löslichkeitskoeffizient $\lambda$ in 
\si{\milli\liter} Gas/(\SI{1000}{\gram} Wasser at \SI{1}{\bar}) 
bei einer Temperatur in \si{\celsius}.}

\begin{tabular}{l *{7}{S[table-format=2.1]} }
\toprule
Gas             & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Temperatur (\si{\celsius})}\\
\cmidrule{2-8}
                & {0}   & {5}   & {10}  & {15}  & {20}  & {25}  & {30}  \\
\midrule
Sauerstoff      & 48,4  & 42,3  & 37,5  & 33,6  & 30,6  & 28,0  & 26,0  \\
Luft            & 28,6  & 25,5  & 22,4  & 20,4  & 18,3  & 16,3  & 15,3  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like that idea. Didn't think of it, I might do it that way.